# Issues finding VBA libraries with old objects (Table), need to get an access DB up and running

Tags: vba, object, ms-access

I'm trying to compile something that was developed in 97' in the 2013 Access. I'm getting object type errors and can't for the life of me find the libraries these object types exist in.

Immediately this is type Table.

```
Dim MyTable As Table
```

Anyone have good VBA experience they can help me out with here?

Ultimately I think I need to find a package of old libraries to install locally.

Comment: Have to use Access 2000-2010 to convert file to version 2013 can run.

Comment: `Dim MyTable As Table` is suspicious, can you add some code how this object is used?

Comment: "table" suggests a reference to Excel. "table" was/is not a native object to access. It also could suggest a reference to ADO - but if this really was running as access 97 (23 years old!!!), then I have to doubt that ADO was being used, so best guess would be a excel reference. A quick glance at the code using "table" would revel this answer. Was this code running as access 97 or in fact say access 2000. If 2000, then it could very well be ADO - but as noted, a quick glance at the code using "table" would tell you this.